# creating a for loop in Haskell

Tags: loops, haskell

I am learning functional programming Haskell.

I have the requirement that I need to read an integer value and max value from the command line, and I need to determine if the integer value is in the range from `[1 to max value]`. I need to determine if any range's value is divided by the integer value.

For example:

```
program 5 20
```

then I need to check if any value from `[1, 2, ..., 20]` is divisible by 5 in sorted order.

How to write such function?

I have read the argument as

```
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    let first_divisor = args !! 0
    let upper_bound = args !! 1

    let x = read first_divisor :: Integer
    let y = read upper_bound :: Integer


    --print args
    --putStrLn first_divisor
    --putStrLn second_divisor
    --putStrLn upper_bound
    isDivisible  x y
```

I need to write this isDivisible function which loops from 1 to y and if rem of (1/x 2/x ....y/x), it prints success or failed.

I have figured the loop as:

```
repeatNTimes 0  = return ()
repeatNTimes n  =
 do
     -- my stuff

  repeatNTimes (n-1)
```

However, this will iterate from n to 0, I want to iterate from 1 to 20.

How can I do this in Haskell so that I can check my even odd value?

Comment: Is that the IO Monad you're using? That should be a pure function.

Comment: @Carcigenicate no i havenot used monad ? monad provides me the loop functionality directly??

Comment: You're using `do` and `return`. What Monad is that for? Do you understand what `return` does in Haskell? It's **very** different from every other language. `return` is **not** used to return a value from a function.

Comment: @nbro hope the question is clear now :)

Comment: To flip the order of iteration, just swap `-- my stuff` and `repeatNTimes (n-1)`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need loop when you have a list

Use `map` and `mapM`

```
isDivisible :: Int -> Int -> [String]
isDivisible firstDivisor upperBound = map (isDivided firstDivisor) [1 .. upperBound]

isDivided :: Int -> Int -> String
isDivided 0 _ = "Failed"
isDivided d x = if mod x d == 0
                then "Success"
                else "Failed"

main :: IO ()
main = do
    input <- getLine
    let args = words input
    let first_divisor = args !! 0
    let upper_bound = args !! 1

    let x = read first_divisor :: Int
    let y = read upper_bound :: Int

    let results = isDivisible  x y

    mapM_ putStrLn results
```